Generalized Rotational Matrix for n-dimensional Euclidean Vector Spaces
$R_{ij}(\theta) := \begin{bmatrix}I_{i-1} & 0 & ... & ... & 0 \\ 
0 & \cos(\theta) & 0 & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & I_{j-i-1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta) & 0\\
0 & ... & ... & 0 & I_{n-j}\end{bmatrix}$
$R_{ij}$ is a transformation matrix of the linear mapping $\Phi : V \rightarrow V$ on an n-dimensional Euclidean vector space V, and it basically rotates (counter-clockwise) a vector's i and j components by angle $\theta$. I am going to use the standard basis used to describe $\mathbb{R^3}$ (i.e., ($e_1, e_2, e_3)$ or (x, y, z)). The question I have is with the way the matrix is defined. To rotate a vector on the $e_2$ (y) axis, we get the following:
$R_{13}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & 0 & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$
The above matrix is clearly wrong. The correct matrix is the following:
$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & 0 & \sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$
Is the y-axis just the exception or am I missing something about the above definition?

It depends on your convention on induced orientation of coordinate planes. Usually, one orients these using the ordered basis $(e_i, e_j)$, $i<j$, but maybe you follow a different convention.

May be I misunderstood your concern, but I think your question is handled here? Why do the signs of $\sin\theta$ change in 3d rotation matrices about the different coordinate axes?. I'm prepared to be wrong, though. So, please clarify!

The right interpretation of that matrix is that it rotates in the $ij$-plane of $n$-space, rotating the positive $i$-axis towards the positive $j$-axis by some small amount (at least for $\theta$ small).
In your case, $R_{13}$ does exactly that: it sends the positive $x$-axis towards the positive $z$ axis when $\theta$ is, say, $\pi/6$, for in that case, the matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(\pi/6) & 0 & -\sin(\pi/6) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin(\pi/6) & 0 & \cos(\pi/6) 
\end{pmatrix} \approx
\begin{pmatrix}
0.866 & 0 & -0.5 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0.866 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
You can see that when you multiply this by the unit vector $e_1$ along the $x$-axis, you get $\pmatrix{0.866\\0\\0.5}$, which is indeed $e_1$ turned a little bit towards $e_3$.
More generally, it's useful to think of rotating in $n$-space as a combination of rotations along various 2-planes, rather than "about an axis"; in 3-space those two are the same, because $1 + 2 = 3$, but that doesn't generalize very well. For instance, in $4$-space, the matrix
$$
M = R_{12}(0.1) R_{34}(0.2)
$$
leaves no axis invariant, but does leave the $xy$- and $zw$-planes setwise invariant.

BTW, with the magic of quaternions, it's not too hard to write down a general formula for a matrix $R(v, t)$ that rotates about an axis $v$ by an amount $t$ in a way that "looks right" in the sense that you want (i.e., a small rotation 'about y' sends the positive $z$-axis towards the positive $x$-axis, rather than the other way about). A search for "quaternion" and "rotation" will yield a jackpot of information about this.

If I think of the matrix as just rotating vectors along 2-planes, then depending on the planes we choose, it would either be a "clockwise" or "counter-clockwise" rotation. Does that not cause problems?

Think of the planes as oriented planes, i.e., they're spanned by an ordered pair of orthogonal vectors $u$ and $v$, and for a small rotation, $u$ is moved to $u'$, a vector in the positive-v halfplane. But if you look at the example I gave, and modify it slightly to $R_{12}(0.1) R_{34}(-0.2)$, you end up with a rotation that's "positive" in the 1-2 plane and "negative" in the 3-4 plane. And at that point, you realize that you really need to rethink your understanding of what constitutes a "rotation," because it's not the thing you might intuitively think from 2D and 3D examples.

I understand now. Thank you!
